# PHP - Server Side HTML <iframe> Parsing / Rendering

Tags: php, html, parsing, rendering

i`m having some dificulties on formulating a correct way to solve this problem:

i have some html documents from external source that i have to do a bulk-parsing and store them in a database for some kind of a offline viewer (intranet) everything fine until there.

but there is a trouble there, some of them have a iframe inside of it (and some of them, have another iframe inside a iframe), and i need to grab their full content.

There is a way to render html (iframes) in a server side way instead loading it on local browser to get their rendered content?

i have tried some ways to do it, like file_get_contents, curl and even messed with PHP buffering (ob_start / ob_get_contents) trying to get these contents correctly, but none of them seems to solve my problem.

there is a pratical way or even a library instead of writing a brand new parser to do it? and if i have to write this, there is a good pratice tips to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I dont think these PHP functions can help you out here, since you'd have to basically parse the HTML document yourself for these iframes. PHP doesnt do that automatically. But instead of doing this all yourself, you can use software for this. I did use "httrack" in the past for this, I'm sure its still around and good to use.

Comment: but there is something to php related? it's because is a bulk process, that i have to do inside my system!

Comment: "httrack" is smart enough to follow links and iframes.